# Finding number of character occurrences in string (mips 32)

Tags: string, character, mips32

I'm writing a code that takes a string and a character from user as input, Then finds number of occurrences of the character in the string.
Here is my attempt:

```
.data 
string:      .space 100                    # allc space for string 
.text
main: 
la $a0, string                             # input string
li $a1, 100                                # maximum size of string
li $v0, 8                                  # represents reading string
syscall                                    # call system
la $s0, 0($a0)                             # $s0 contains address of first element of the string
    
li $v0, 12                                 # 12 represents reading character
syscall                                    # call system  
move $s2, $v0                              # $s2= character
li $s1, 100                                # $s1= maximum size of string
                       
li  $t4, 0                                 # count (number of occurrances)
li  $t0, 0                                 # i(index)
loop:
bge $t0, $s1, print                        # i>= string length, exit                            
add $t1, $s0, $t0                          # &A[i]
lb  $t2, 0($t1)                            # A[i]
bne $t2, $s2, skip                         # skip increasing the counter if item does not equal               
add $t4, $t4, 1                            # otherwise increment the counter    
skip: 
add $t0, $t0, 1                            # increment index
j  loop                                    # go back to loop
print:                                     # print the result
addi $v0, $t4, 0                           # $v0= $v4= number of occurrences
li $v0,1                                   # 1 represents printing integer                   
syscall                                    # call system    
# Terminate the program
li $v0, 10                                 # 10 represents exit
syscall                                    # call system
```

But my code is not working properly. It prints a very large number instead of number of occurrences. I even checked it for string with the same size as the space allocated. But it still gives wrong result. Is this problem related to length of string or something else? Please help me debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
        .data 
    string:      .space 100                    # allc space for string 
    .text
    main: 
    la $a0, string                             # input string
    li $a1, 100                                # maximum size of string
    li $v0, 8                                  # represents reading string
    syscall                                    # call system

    li $v0, 12                                 # 12 represents reading character
    syscall                                    # call system  
    move $s2, $v0                              # $s2= character
    li $s1, 100                                # $s1= maximum size of string
               
    li  $t4, 0                                 # count (number of occurrances)
    li  $t0, 0                                 # i(index)

    bge $t0, $s1, print                        # i>= string length, exit    
    loop:                        

    lb  $s0,($a0)                              # the first character of string into $s0 
    bne $s0, $s2, skip                         # skip increasing the counter if item does not equal               
    add $t4, $t4, 1                            # otherwise increment the counter    
    skip: 
    addiu $a0, $a0, 1                            # increment index
    beq $s0,0,print                             # go to print label if $s0=0 so $s0 ='\0' 
    j  loop                                    # go back to loop
    print:                                     # print the result
    #addi $v0, $t4, 0                           # $v0= $v4= number of occurrences
    li $v0,1                                   # 1 represents printing integer                   
    move $a0,$t4                               # $a0=$t4 = number of occurances of character
    syscall                                    # call system    
    # Terminate the program
    li $v0, 10                                 # 10 represents exit
    syscall                                    # call system
```